# Set properties by reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I have this:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, decimal> update in updates)
{
salesorder.GetType().InvokeMember(update.Key, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.SetProperty, Type.DefaultBinder, salesorder, update.Value);
}
```

I found the example on this site but it was using a string, my example is decimal but it says cannot convert from decimal to object[]

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The last parameter has to be an `object[]`, so you need to wrap the `decimal`:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, decimal> update in updates)
{
    salesorder.GetType().InvokeMember(update.Key, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.SetProperty, Type.DefaultBinder, salesorder, new object[] { update.Value });
}
```

If you want to set values 'deeper' (as indicated in your comments):

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, decimal> update in updates)
{
    var property = salesorder.GetType().InvokeMember(update.Key, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.GetProperty, Type.DefaultBinder, salesorder, new object[] { });
    property.GetType().InvokeMember("Value", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.SetProperty, Type.DefaultBinder, property, new object[] { update.Value });
}
```

Comment: Thanks - i'm getting this now - Method salesorder.new_operations_dealerinvoicefunder' not found. I'm trying to set the property value not call a method by that name.

Comment: Then your `Key` is wrong. You can use `InvokeMember` for properties, fields or members alike: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66btctbe(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I think it's because the property I need to set is a level down, i.e. salesorder.new_operations_dealerfunderinvoice.Value = value instead of salesorder.new_operations_dealerfunderinvoice = value. Is that possible?